# "apache2" is using port 80, but why is apache even running?

Tags: apache2

I don't know why apache is running and I'd like to investigate and see if it's even being used. I am weak with the CLI, and when I dug into the log files they were supposedly empty. It's blocking my port 80 and I'd like to know if I can kill the service and uninstall it without ruining something I'm unaware of.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to see whether anything is using Apache would be to check the log files. So long as Apache is configured in a semi-standard manner, you can see every incoming request.

Try this:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. List the files in `/var/log/apache2`:

   ```
   $ ll /var/log/apache2/*access*
   ```

   This should give you something that looks like this (minus the Japanese dates):

   ```
   drwxr-x---  2 root adm      4096  2月  5 00:00 ./
   drwxrwxr-x 18 root syslog   4096  2月  5 00:00 ../
   -rw-r-----  1 root adm         0  2月  6  2020 access.log
   -rw-r-----  1 root adm         0  2月  2 00:00 hrtool-access.log
   -rw-r-----  1 root adm    105344  2月  1 14:01 hrtool-access.log.1
   -rw-r--r--  1 root root    14701  1月 29 22:10 hrtool-access.log.2.gz
   -rw-r--r--  1 root root        0  2月  3 16:33 kirin-access.log
   -rw-r-----  1 root adm         0  2月  4  2020 other_vhosts_access.log
   ```

   With this I can quickly look through the file sizes and dates. For the example above there have been recent accesses to one of the virtual hosts this week. If nothing is accessing your Apache installation, then the dates for these files may be weeks, months, or years in the past.

Before removing Apache completely, which could have unexpected consequences on any application that might need it, you can first disable it:

```
$ sudo service apache2 stop
```

If you see that all of your applications and systems continue working as expected, you can completely remove Apache like this:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Remove the Apache tools:

   ```
   $ sudo apt purge apache2 apache2-utils apache2.2-bin apache2-common
   ```
2. Clean up the packages:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get autoremove
   ```
3. Look for any remaining directories:

   ```
   $ whereis apache2
     apache2: /etc/apache2
   ```
4. Remove any remnants:

   ```
   $ sudo rm -rf /etc/apache2
   ```

Done and done.

Comment: Pro Tip: ALWAYS read the output of Steps 1 and 2. Proceed only if you fully understand and agree with the list of removals. That output is there to protect you from folly.

Comment: Apache2.2-bin not installed, and apach2-common package not found. That alright?

Comment: If things are not found or installed, then that's less work for the computer to do. Feel free to edit the `apt` command to suit your situation and, like user535733 says, always read the output. You'll get a list of packages that will be removed along with Apache. So long as everything is good, proceed. Otherwise, just leave Apache as stopped.

Answer (score 2):

If you have `aptitude` installed do

`aptitude why apache2`

and it will tell you why it's there.